# Resize the renderer inbetween two renders

Tags: javascript, three.js, raytracing

I'm building a webGL ray tracer relying on three.js.
In order to speed up computations and make it real time, instead of ray tracing all the pixels of the screen, I'm considering just a subset of them (I consider block of pixels instead of each pixel independently).

Therefore I'm using a differed shading, that is:

1. apply the ray tracer to the subset of pixels, and store the resulting image in a texture
   (the texture has size screenWidth/blockSize,screenHeight/blockSize).
2. render the texture on a full screen quad

Here is the three.js code for it:

```
// first rendering: render the scene in a low resolution texture
rayTracingRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth/blockSize,window.innerHeight/blockSize);
rayTracingRenderer.render(scene, camera, texture, true);

// second rendering: render the texture on a full screen quad
rayTracingRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
rayTracingRenderer.render(scenePostProcess, cameraRTT);
```

In order to compute a lower amount of pixels for the first rendering, I simply decrease the size of the renderer. I resize it afterwards in order to compute the right amount of pixel.

However this code doesn't work: it prints a black screen with white noise.
Apparently the problem comes from the fact that ***I resize the renderer between two `render()` call***. Indeed, it works when I set the resolution once for all, whatever the value is.

For instance, when I set the resolution to screenWidth/blockSize,screenHeight/blockSize I get a small image on my screen, and when I set it to screenWidth,screenHeight I got a fullscreen blurred image. (That fullscreen blurred image is the expected result has the texture size as low resolution, but the number of pixels processed is the number of pixels of the screen therefore I'm not speeding up anything at all.)

Can you spot any mistake I could have made, or is it a bug and I should go on a workaround ?

Comment: I had similar problems when I tried to recycle the main ui renderer for thumbnail generation, resizing it on the fly for one-off thumb renders. Not sure what the problem was, but setting a small timeout between resize and render helped in my case. Best of luck!

Comment: You can always use a second renderer that has smaller size.

Comment: @mrdoob, could you help?

Comment: @gaitat Having a second renderer wasn't a good solution as I was passing a texture from one to the other, and it seemed like two different gl context were created.

Turns out, I don't think the issue has anything to do with three js at all as I've been running the same code on a better laptop and it was working fine. 

This bug is regarding GPU and webGL support rather than three js.

Comment: @Jacko Glad you figured it out.